# Class 'Illuminate\support\Facades\Redirect' not found laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I transfer my Laravel project localhost to live server. First, I upload my all Laravel file, live server in httpdocs folder, and then, Laravel public folder all file move to server root directory httpdocs folder. and then I changed index.php two lines.

1. require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; "to" 
   require **DIR**.'/vendor/autoload.php';
2. $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; "to"
   $app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

My home page working good. www.impressive-fashions.com

But, When I try to login by admin email and password my dashboard page. showing this massage

```
"Class 'Illuminate\support\Facades\Redirect' not found"
```

### Showing this error By Image

image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQvi7.jpg

**This is my admin Link**: www.impressive-fashions.com/admin 
**Admin Mail**: test@mail.com 
**Admin Password**: 123

This Is My **Admincontroller.php** code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;
use Illuminate\support\Facades\Redirect;
session_start();

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('admin_login');
    }

    public function dashboard(Request $request){
        $admin_email=$request->admin_email;
        $admin_password=md5($request->admin_password);
        $result=DB::table('tbl_admin')
                ->where('admin_email', $admin_email)
                ->where('admin_password', $admin_password)
                ->first();
                if ($result) {
                    Session::put('admin_name', $result->admin_name);
                    Session::put('admin_id', $result->admin_id);
                    return Redirect::to('/dashboard'); 
                } else {
                    Session::put('message', 'Email or Password Invalid');
                    return Redirect::to('/admin');
                }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, change `use Illuminate\support\Facades\Redirect;` to `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;` also have you ran `composer install` ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yamen Steal showing the same problem. I did composer install